# How to validate Azure ad b2c token using PHP?

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm creating Azure ad b2c login. After I login from it they give us a token(key). I need to know how to validate that token and how to get that token from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article describes the steps:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/README.md

You don't need to call the server, the `id_token` can be validated on your own system

Comment: bro i already do that. In my app user can login using microsoft acc and do stuffs. To find how do it and when he is login to identy i try save token using JWS but i dnt know how to do it using php. Can you help me to that

Comment: Hi, @Malith Pamuditha Fernando. Have you try to use https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt to satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Hi @MalithPamudithaFernando, could  you please clarify your question? Do you mean you have get the id_token from identity provider and now do not know how to validate it with `php-jwt`?